# Unable to set hyperlink to Div

Tags: html, css

I've built a page to import into Mailchimp as an email template. Everything seems fine, but I can't get an embedded image to work as a hyperlink, let alone a mailto.

I think the margins may be messing it up, and I've tried to change them, as well as the positioning, but I get the same none-result every time I change it. I've added a link to the logo at the bottom that works, so I'm not going mad.

```css
.city-park {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -250px;
  z-index: -10;
}

.diamond {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 544px;
  left: 30%;
}

.icon-container {
  width: 700px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  /*609px;*/
  background-color: #fff;
}

.first-div {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}

.second-div {
  width: 34%;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}

.third-div {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 120px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="city-park"><img src="http://trainstorm.co.uk/jll/images/JLL-CityOfficePark.jpg" width="700" height="859" alt="JLL-City Office Park" /></div>
<div class="diamond"><img src="http://trainstorm.co.uk/jll/images/JLL-EnquireNow.png" width="283" height="130" alt="JLL - Enquire Now" /></div>
<div class="icon-container">
  <div class="first-div"><img src="http://trainstorm.co.uk/jll/images/JLL-Space-Icon.jpg" width="110" height="110" alt="JLL - Office Space" />
    <div class="icon-text-box"><span class="corner-orange">60,500 sqft office space</span> <span class="corner-text">available as a self-contained building or on a floor-by-floor basis</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="second-div"><img src="http://trainstorm.co.uk/jll/images/JLL-Energy-Icon.jpg" width="110" height="110" alt="JLL - Energy Efficient" />
    <div class="icon-text-box"><span class="corner-orange">Energy efficient</span> <span class="corner-text">building management system</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="third-div"><img src="http://trainstorm.co.uk/jll/images/JLL-Refurb-Icon.jpg" width="110" height="110" alt="JLL - Fully Refurbished" />
    <div class="icon-text-box"><span class="corner-orange">Newly refurbished</span> <span class="corner-text">(available April 2019)</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

I've included the code for the issue area and those above and below it.

I'm testing it here: http://trainstorm.co.uk/jll/JLL%20One%20Leeds%20Email.html

A band of focus shows up underneath the "Enquire now" image when the code is inspected, but even that isn't clickable.

Comment: When you say embedded image as hyperlink, are you missing anchor tags in provided code snippet?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've moved them about so much. This is what I've tried most, although they've been inside the div as well. <a href="http://residential.jll.co.uk/contact-us/offices/leeds-estate-agents">
  <div class="diamond"><img src="images/JLL-EnquireNow.png" width="283" height="130" alt="JLL - Enquire Now"/></div>
  </a>

Comment: Have you tried surrounding image tag with anchor tag? Because i can see the code snippet to be working fine when image tag is wrapped inside anchor tag.

Comment: It doesn't work whether the href is wrapping the div or just the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be with the `container` class - specifically, it has a z-index of -1000 that makes all its contents appear "behind" the other stuff on the page.

I added a link inside your `diamond` element like this:

```
<div class="diamond">
   <a href="residential.jll.co.uk/contact-us/offices/leeds-estate-agents">
      <img src="images/JLL-EnquireNow.png" alt="JLL - Enquire Now">
   </a>
</div>
```

Which also requires a line of CSS so that the link area fills the diamond:

```
.diamond a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

That link became clickable the moment I removed the z-index on `container`, although doing that also caused your `city-park` image to disappear.

To keep the image and allow that item to be clickable, I recommend using a background image on `city-park` instead.

Comment: You're a superstar. And I'm a numpty. Thank you. I've rejigged the z-index on a few things and it works perfectly now. Thank you for your expert help.